# Sed insert, copy and change, append a line of matching string

Tags: linux, unix, sed

Tool: sed

Requirement: I want sed to find a line with matching string

```
. Copy the line and comment one line
. Modify  the other line      
. Insert a string above the two lines.
```

Example:
File contents:

```
*  soft nproc  1024
root soft nproc unlimited
```

Task: Search for string 1024 and comment it and replace 1024 with 2048 and then add a string above it.

File contents after modification:

```
#######RAJASEKHAR#####Modified for DSD######
#* soft nproc 1024
* soft nproc  2048
root soft nproc unlimited
```

Comment: Do the homework/exam on your own! Have you even checked the `sed` syntax?!

Comment: I googled for it but couldn't get the solution, in which "matching line is copied,  commented at the same time the line should be modified. In addition, I want to place a string 2 lines above the matching line.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sed -n '$i\
#######RAJASEKHAR#####Modified for DSD######\
#* soft nproc 1024\
* soft nproc  2048\
root soft nproc unlimited' old_file > new_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you've already read the manual of sed and everything you could get from the net on the topic a couple of times, you just can't see the items that are important to you now.
Let's emphasize them

- first of all, regular expressions (at least the simplest ones), that
  is regexp
- s/regexp/string/
- \(subregexp\) inside regexp
- & inside the string element of s/.../.../
- \n inside the string element of s/.../.../
- \1 inside the string element of s/.../.../

And now you just need to put them together.

Comment: I googled for it but couldn't get the solution, in which "matching line is copied,  commented at the same time the line should be modified. In addition, I want to place a string 2 lines above the matching line.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation of the items of the list I wrote above? If yes, didn't they seem like the pieces of the jigsaw you have to solve?